# How do I do a raw query using Nest with object initializer syntax?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to do a search in ElasticSearch using Nest.  I want to use the object initializer syntax because I need to build the parts of the search dynamically.  I have figured out how to build much of the request, but am not clear how I would initialize a Raw Query.  The OIS doesn't seem to have QueryRaw as a parameter to the request.

Code that I have now:

```
var searchResults = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
    .Index("myIndex"),
    .Type("myType),
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .DateHistogram("my_date_histogram", h => h
            .Field("DateField")
            .Interval("day")
         )
     )
     .QueryRaw(queryText)
)
```

Code that I am trying to create:

```
var request = new SearchRequest<dynamic>
{
    Index = "MyIndex",
    Type = "MyType",
    QueryRaw = <doesn't exist>
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<dynamic>(new SearchRequest
{
    Query = new RawQuery(yourquery)
});
```

Tested with NEST 2.0.0.alpha2 and ES 2.1.0

Comment: Thanks Rob.  It looks like maybe this does not work with Nest 1.7.1?  I tried upgrading to Nest 2.0.0 alpha 2, but that caused an update to Newtonsoft 8.0.1 (which then broken other installed Azure packages) and DateHistogramAggregator no longer resolved.

Comment: I wasn't able to handle this with 1.7.1. Looks like `DateHistogramAggregator ` has been renamed to `DateHistogramAggregation`. Regarding Json 8.0.1 ... yeah :/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do raw queries using the new object structure:

```
var response = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
    .Query(qry => qry
        .Raw(yourRawQueryStringHere)
    )
);
```